# My computer can't sleep or hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

**My computer can't sleep or hibernate.** 
After sleep (hibernate) it shows only black screen and I can't use my computer (I'm pressing the power button for 10s turn off the computer and starting again to be possible any action)

It sleeps randomly (one time it sleeps, the second time it can't sleep and the black screen appears)

I'm using Windows 10 Pro - all updates installed. 
**I saw some posts on forums but this isn't duplicate, because tried almost solutions, that I found**

I tried these things:

- `powercfg -hibernate on`; `powercfg /h on` in the administrator cmd.
- I changed the power setting and slected when sharing media: `allow computer to sleep`
- I exported my energy settings
- I updated the BIOS and sleep worked 2 days, after that the issue continue
- ...and other small useless things

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** *This problem happens when there are many started programs or if the computer has been working for a long time without being turned off.*

**I am very sad and I need help...** Please help! **How to solve this issue?**

Comment: Please add your hardware. Is there any chance that 1 or more programs prevent windows from waking up correctly? I once saw that happen when I pressed the standby-button while in a game. Anyway, if there is a chance for that, please tell us your programs. Also, your statement isn't consistent: `My computer can't sleep or hibernate.` vs. `This problem happens when there are many started programs or if the computer has been working for a long time without being turned off.` So does it work if you hibernate immediately after booting your computer up? If so, I'd look for a program that's to blame.

Comment: @flolilolilo OK. My hardware is: Dell Inspiron 3537. Other system information here: imgur.com/a/fnyLm 
I also thinking about programs that prevent sleep. I'm using: Google Chrome, Slack, cmd (started local Node server from cmd), XAMPP (started local apache and MySQL server).
The sleep and the hibernation working right away rebooting or starting after shut down...

I think you can help me now...

Comment: @user12345678 So start those programs one by one and see which one breaks hibernation.

Comment: I have the same problem. First time PC hibernates well, but second time - black screen and power is on. But actually I don't need to press power button for 10s to break from this: if press any key on the keyboard or mouse button I can see my desktop.
If I try to hibernate with all apps closed nothing really changes.
Similarly, tried all solutions from google but still no luck. Even tried to reinstall windows but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to check the running programs? Did you check if there is any static electricity? Is there too much wire around the computer case? Unplug all the cables, check if there is any static electricity. **Even try to remove dust with a fan!**, what now?